# Rails : I made form_for to post data to certain action but it doen't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, form-for

Now I'm trying to use mailgun gem to send e-mail. So I made a form_for help like this.

Here is my **index.html.erb** file.

```
 <form class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>FEEDBACK</legend>
      <div class="form-group col-md-12" align="center">
        <%= form_for :feedback, url: feedback_path do |f| %>
          <%= f.text_area :contents, class: "form-control", style: "width:112%", :rows => 5 , :autocomplete => :off %>
          <% unless user_signed_in? %>
            <div class="col-md-12" style="height: 10px"></div>
            <%= f.text_field :from, class: "form-control", style: "width:112%", :autocomplete => :off, :placeholder => "Leave your email" %>
          <% end %>
          <div class="col-md-12" style="height: 10px"></div>
          <%= f.submit "Send", class: "btn btn-default" %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

And this is my **home_controller.rb** file.

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

def feedback_send
    from = params[:feedback][:from]
    contents = params[:feedback][:contents]
    FeedbackMailer.feedback_email(from, contents).deliver_now

    redirect_to :back
end
```

This is **routes.rb** file

```
post '/feedback_send', to: 'home#feedback_send', as: 'feedback'
```

But It doesn't work. It redirected to "http://localhost:3000/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=Whcu6QAF5XGBwYIv8A%2B2r6KvOyXIqc9jC%2BB1y%2Fp4zXQ%3D&feedback%5Bcontents%5D=12312321312&feedback%5Bfrom%5D=&commit=Send".

When I look at log of server, it shows like this.

```
Started GET "/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=Whcu6QAF5XGBwYIv8A%2B2r6KvOyXIqc9jC%2BB1y%2Fp4zXQ%3D&feedback%5Bcontents%5D=12312321312&feedback%5Bfrom%5D=&commit=Send" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-06 22:08:00 +0900
```

I can't catch what is wrong here.

Comment: Try changing `post '/feedback_send', to: 'home#feedback_send', as: 'feedback'` to `post 'feedback_send', to: 'home#feedback_send', as: 'feedback'`

Comment: I tried, but exactly same....